# Acceleration of a sphere with cavity in the incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, torque

[image: figure]

Does the object in the figure above undergo an uniformly accelerated motion?

(Let's assume that the object rolls without slipping, ignore $\theta$)

I tried to find acceleration using free body diagram and torque equation. If I set the origin of torque to be centre of mass, the moment arm of friction changes all the time. I can merely calculate moment of inertia using negative mass and find the radius of gyration but fundamentally I wonder whether this object undergoes an uniformly accelerated motion.

Thanks in advance for reading and answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the moment arm is a variable, the torque and angular acceleration will also be variable.  The acceleration is not uniform.

Comment: I asked this question because of the following problem.

Comment: A uniform solid ball contains a hollow spherical cavity at its center, the radius of the cavity being 1/2 the radius of the ball. Show that the acceleration of the ball rolling down a rough inclined plane is just 98/101 of that of a uniform solid ball with no cavity

Comment: Is this question wrong?

Comment: The difference in the question you are asked compared to the one depicted in the image is that the cavity is *centered* WRT the ball. It means that even after rolling, the cavity will be "at the same place" and the lever arm will be the same.

Comment: The sphere and the wheel are definitely different, but both are nonuniform. Given enough run, the wheel will always return to its starting state in terms of the angle where the center of the hole is, but the ball might not ever return to it's initial state, unless it starts out exactly balanced so perfectly that it behaves exactly like the wheel.  On a long enough incline, both the wheel and the sphere are unstable and might leave the surface from time to time.  Atmospheric drag might eventually limit acceleration of both the wheel and the sphere.

Comment: JW Donahue:  Your comment about the non-uniform sphere leaving the surface is interesting given that the center of mass oscillates relative to the surface as the sphere rolls down the incline.  I'm wondering; what wheel are you refering to?